# Add a Clear button functionality in Custom Keyboard using Swift

Tags: swift2, xcode7, uiinputviewcontroller

I use a custom keyboard which contains a delete and a clear button.I can able to delete the letters using this code

```
let obj =  UIInputViewController()
(obj.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
```

Is it any keyword available to clear whole text in a textfield.

NB: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507731/custom-keyboard-clear-button) link but it is not apt for my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no keyword available for deleting the whole text in the textfield through custom keyboard.

To clear all the text that the UITextDocumentProxy object can access in the textfield before the cursor position

```
if let word:String = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput     
{
    for _: Int in 0 ..< word.characters.count {
        self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
    }
}
```

To delete the text after cursor position, you have to move the cursor forward to delete it.

Comment: This is a good start, but will unfortunately not work as expected, since the `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBefore/AfterInput` functions will stop fetching text randomly, often at new paragraphs, and will return a partial result.